# Are the author's attempts correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> The derivative of the function $y=f(x)$ whose graph passes through the point $(3,4)$ at each point $(x,y)$ is $\frac xy$.  Which of the following could this function be?

The author says, we need to find $f(x)$ from the equation $f'(x)=\frac xy$:

But, I don't understand this solution. When you look at the solution, $y$ seems to be constant.  But why? Because, $y=f(x)$ is a function.

[image]

The correct solution would be:

$$\int f(x)d(f(x))=\int x dx$$

$$f^2(x)=x^2+c$$

So, put $f(3)=4$ is enough.

Are the author's attempts correct?

Comment: For the purposes of integrating against $x$ (the $dx$), $y$ is a constant.

Comment: @Randall But, $y=f(x)$?

Comment: Not a bad point.

Comment: The method is completely wrong. Beside the observation before, if $y=\frac{x^2}{2y}+C$ then the solution for $y$ would be a solution of quadratic equation: $2y^2-2Cy-x^2=0$

Comment: If $\phi(x) = {1 \over 2} f^2(x)$ then $\phi'(x) = f(x)f'(x)$ and $\phi'(x) = x$.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: @copper.hat This book is not academic. Just a high school workbook.

Comment: Still, good for others to know.

Comment: @copper.hat I guess, You also think the author's attempt is problematic?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The method is definitely incorrect. The method you outline below is correct

Comment: @HenryLee Thank you for clarification. I understood.